# Which one is better Nuxt+Vuetify or Directus?

Tags: voyager, directus

I'm about to work on a rebuild/revamp legacy application that has CMS/Admin to monitor surveys. The current stack for the Admin is Voyager+Laravel while VueJs is use for the surveys.

I'm thinking of moving away to Voyager and decouple the front-end entirely from the back-end.

Challenge: I need to create a fast, flexible, and reusable application that is easier to add new features as they arise.

What do you guys think the best way to approach this? Pros and Cons?

- NuxtJs+Vuetify for the front-end and laravel/lumen for the back-end API.
- Directus for entire Admin + API and retain VueJs for the survey
- stay with the current stack but keep it up to date

Answer (score 4):

By relying on Directus, you prevent having to build / maintain the admin backend and API, which should save you a lot of work. With the headless API in place, you can build the front-end however you like. You could also go with NuxtJs + Vuetify for the front-end and Directus for the back-end API.

Note: I'm involved with the Directus project so obviously biased.

Comment: I second this, Directus is a headless CMS so using it on the backend to handle all of your api stuff is good while leaving Nuxtjs on the frontend to handle the ui.